# Pass variable from end of function to beggining of same function on next run

Tags: typescript

Is it possiible to send variable that is set on the end of function to same function to be used on beggining in next run

> 

```
Function function1 {
If(val1.id ==5){
Console.log(val1.id val1.name)
}
else{}

Val1.id = 5
Val1.name = 'name'
}
```

Trying to highlight text to sone colour but on next run to set it back to original highlight colour

I should pass colorcode, textrange

```
    var target = pText.substring(feedback.location[y].start, feedback.location[y].end);
            var ranges = range.split([target], true, true, false);
            var myR = ranges.getFirst();
            var startRange = myR.getRange(Word.RangeLocation.end);
            var ranges1 = range.split([target], true, false, false);
            var myR1 = ranges1.getFirst();
            var endRange = myR1.getRange(Word.RangeLocation.end);
            var targetRange = startRange.expandTo(endRange);
setRange(targetRange)


function setRange(PreRange: any){
  PreviousRange = PreRange
}
```

Comment: You cannot access a variable/function before you declare it. What do you need to do?

Comment: Need to use that variable in next run. Actually, need to remember colorcode and range so i can use it when i run function again and than assign new data to variable

Answer (score 0):

Well it is possible, if you create global variable like in example:

```
var temp = 0;
function changeColor() {
    if (temp) {
        document.getElementById("toggle").style.color = "blue";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("toggle").style.color = "red";
    }
    temp = 1;
};
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ud2Lxt0e/2/)

I don't know if that is your case, if not maybe you can give something more specific.

Comment: in my case PreviousRange and TargetRange should be same when i select same wordbut its not. PreviousRange is from previous function execution